# Android: How to access from activity to update private variable of another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, arraylist, private, start-activity

I am trying to do something like that , Firstly , there is a MainActivity which stores courses in ArrayList and these courses are showed by listview.After that , I pass to another activity which is called as ShowDetailActivity with startActivity() to show course details when I click list view element.Then, I pass to another activity which is called EditCourseActivity to edit course which is shown by ShowDetailActivity. The problem is that When I want to edit course , I have to access MainActivity 's Arraylist (private) but I cannot pass with startActivity() because MainActivity did restart (reinstalled) that's why there is no courses on arraylist. The question is How can access from EditCourseActivity to MainActivity 's arraylist to show updated courses ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the course information in a singleton class

```
public class CourseHolder{
    public static CourseHolder instance=null;
    public static CourseHolder getInstance(){
        if(instance==null){
            instance=new CourseHolder();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    private Course courses[];
    private CourseHolder(){
        courses=new Course[10];
    }
    public void setCourse(int index, Course course){
        courses[index]=course;
    }
    public Course[] getCourses(){
        return courses;
    }
}
```

In the EditCourseActivity, after editing, store the updated course information in the copy of CourseHolder

In MainActivity.onResume(), call listView.setAdapter(null), then refresh it with the data inside the CourseHolder

Comment: Thanks for your answer Patrick, now I am working on your solution .If I have a problem , I will ask you again about your answer.

Comment: Again thanks for your attention , your solution is good for practice I will use it to solve problem. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

As a generic answer: detach the data from its representation. You can achieve this in many ways:

- Singleton wrapper for your array list
- To be android specific: wrap your array in a ContentProvider
- Use Android SDK SQL database support

Comment: Thanks for answer, Yes I know ContentProvider and SQLite database are solution but Up to here I cannot use them.